# Understanding docker principles

Tags: docker, web-deployment

I have made a quite simple golang server and I need to deploy it to a digitalocean droplet.

I know that there can be issues with cross-building go apps in case they use cgo, so to not to think about it in future I decided to use docker, so my app will be build and run always in same environment.

The first thing I dont get is about developing an app. When I create a Dockerfile I use commands to add files from my project directory into newly created docker image. Then I run the container created from this image. But what if I edit my code? - as I understood I must stop the container, remove an image and then build it again. This is a bit tricky for such a common situation - or am I doing things wrong?

Second one - I have created a docker droplet on a DO: Whats the way to deploy my app?

- I have to push my image to any docker repository and pull it on to the droplet?
- Or I can upload it directly?
- Or I have to scp my source code to droplet and run same process as on my local machine, building image and then runnjng a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if I edit my code? - as I understood I must stop the container, remove an image and then build it again. This is a bit tricky for such a common situation - or am I doing things wrong?

Don't delete the image just rebuild it.  It will be much faster than the first initial build. Also why is it tricky?  It's just one or two commands, you can create a bash or .bat script if it gets annoying.

> I have created a docker droplet on a DO: Whats the way to deploy my app?

All three options are a possibility.  For the second one you would have to set up your VM as a docker-hub repo which might be more than you need.  Using docker hub isn't bad.  You could also just build the image on your server.  I recommend using docker hub for it's ease and having watchtower set up on your server to restart your web app on new image pushes.

Edit: the above advice was for a VM not a docker droplet.  I'm not familiar with DO but this article should help:

https://blog.machinebox.io/deploy-machine-box-in-digital-ocean-385265fbeafd